# Бутстрап -пропала анимация

Tags: javascript

Пилю бутстрап в первый раз.
Купил тему, зарегал домен, хост, выгружаю шаблон - пропадает анимация.
Как получается - http://srazusdal.ru/
Как должно быть - http://themeforest.net/item/stark-animated-html-app-landing-page/full_screen_preview/6541466
НУтром чую - где то потерял яваскрипты?
Что делать. Как исправить?
Хостинг - hostinger.ru

Comment: интересно я дождусь того момента, когда наличие диплома из вуза, будет причиной отказа в работе ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error.hostinger.eu/?:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined main.js:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Это ошибки на вашем сайте. Скорее всего нарушена нужная последовательность подгрузки скриптов.

**добавлено**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Вот тут он не загружает jQuery )